# Convert two arrays to a new one using LINQ

Tags: linq

I have two `double[] X` and `double[] Y`.
I want to create a new array Z, where each Zi = Xi * Yi

I wonder if it's possible to do with LINQ?
(I'm learning LINQ now; of course I can use plain for).

Answer (score 10):

It's possible at 4.0, using [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) (that's the definition of zip - combining elements on the same position):

```
double[] Z = X.Zip(Y, (x, y) => x * y).ToArray();
```

On 3.5 you can use [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), which has a custom Zip extension method.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a 3rd party lib or .NET 4.0, you could use 'Select'

```
double[] z = x.Select((d, i) => d * y[i]).ToArray();
```

'i' is the index of element 'd' for the current iteration and it's used here to retrieve the accordant element from y.